# Firefox 89 doesn't see userChrome.css even set toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets=true

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar, userchrome.css

Firefox has just updated and now it doesn't see userChrome.css,  toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets is set to true. I'm trying to hide the scrollbar by

```
html {
    scrollbar-width: none !important;
}
```

and everything worked fine before firefox updated.

I've put the chrome/userChrome.css to every profile folder I have and restarted firefox every time, but it still doesn't see anything from userChrome.css

--

UDP:

Firefox still doesn't see my custom css, but if you want to hide the scrollbars, [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-scrollbars/?utm_content=addons-manager-reviews-link&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_source=firefox-browser) works.

Comment: What are you using for the userChrome.css file? Your own or are you using [Arit-t2’s GitHub custom CSS](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx)? I ask as Arti-t2 updated his CSS four hours ago and it’s working for me (I use it to position the tabs below the bookmark tool bar).

Comment: @RichDeBourke no, I use my own CSS for only hiding the scrollbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

widget.non-native-theme.enabled = false

Answer (score 5):

Try setting `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true`. According to *[How to Create a userChrome.css File](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html#aboutconfig)* (on userchrome.org), Firefox used to look for `chrome/userChrome.css` at startup, but this was discontinued as default behavior starting with Firefox 69, to speed up startup.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I've already mentioned that this property is set to true.

Comment: This worked for me on Firefox 91.0.2 today, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a userChrome file, a userContent.css file is what you would use to style pages that are actually displayed on Firefox

Comment: Do you have references to backup your suggested solution? Unfortunately your answer doesn't explain further how and why using a userContent.css-file fixes the described problem. A short explanation or hyperllink would be very helpful. Greetings ~

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `userContent` is for styling the page, `userChrome` is for styling the browser chrome itself.